# ¿Soñoliento o somnoliento?

Tags: vocabulario, significado, sinónimos

Leyendo (una traducción de) El Conde de Montecristo me acabo de encontrar con *soñoliento*, cuando yo solamente conocía *somnoliento*. Me fijé en el diccionario de la Real Academia y ambas existen. Sin embargo, no me queda claro si hay alguna diferencia en el significado de estas dos palabras.

Comment: Yo creo que no hay diferencia

Comment: El significado es el mismo, aunque me da la sensación de que soñoliento es un arcaicismo y está en desuso.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

El significado de las dos palabras es similar.

Llama la atención, sin embargo que:

- En el CORDE apenas aparece una veintena de casos de **somnoliento**   frente a más de 200 de **soñoliento**
- Según Google Ngram Viewer, **soñoliento** se ha utilizado mucho más que **somnoliento** hasta hace relativamente poco:
  [image]
- Aunque **soñoliento** aparece desde los primeros diccionarios (1495 Nebrija), **somnoliento** no aparece hasta el diccionario de la RAE de
  ¡ 1985 !

Parece, pues, que aunque ambas palabras son antiguas, el uso ha sido mayoritariamente de **soñoliento** hasta muy recientemente.